# Problems implementing a Django Custom Template Tag

Tags: django, python-2.7

I need to implement a template tag that will return a string with a collection of items from an object.

I had created the following structure:

```
produtos/        
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        produto_tags.py
```

produto_tags.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import template
from django.template import Node
from produto.models import Produto
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

register = template.Library()

@register.tag
def get_all_tags(parser, token):
    args = token.split_contents()
    return ProdutoTemplateNode(args[1])


class ProdutoTemplateNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, produto):
        self.produto = produto

    def render(self, context):
        list = []
        produto = template.Variable(self.produto).resolve(context)
        tags = produto.tags.all()
        if tags:
            for tag in tags:
                list.append(tag.name)
            return ", ".join(list)
        else:
            return u'Não existem tags para este produto'
```

Template:

```
{% load produto_tags %}
...
    {% for produto in produtos %}
        <li id="{{ produto.ordenacao }}" data-tags="{% get_all_tags produto %}">
            ...
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Não existem produtos cadastrados no sistema</p>
{% endif %}
```

I am receiving this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /concrete/nossos-sites.html
Invalid block tag: 'get_all_tags', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'
```

I read other threads where people said this error occurs if the Tag does not exist and it seems to be the case. I've been looking on the djangoproject.com documentation as well and I could not find any clue about what might be happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was tricky, even though simple:

First, there was another 'produto_tags.py' in another folder elsewhere in the project:

```
project/
    common/
        templatetags/
            produtos_tags.py
    produtos/
        templatetags/
            produtos_tags.py
```

So, at first I have moved all code from produtos/templatetags/ to common/templatetags/. But when I did it Django started whining about not finding the produtos_tags from produtos. Afterwards I got the code back to produtos/templatetags/ and renamed the file to tags_produtos.py, what had worked to show the easy part that is my wrong import below:

Wrong:

```
from produto.models import Produto
```

Correct:

```
from produtos.models import Produto
```

Answer (score 3):

Template tag files need to be inside a directory called `templatetags` inside your app.

Comment: Daniel, I made a mistake on the description. I have corrected the description now.

Comment: templatetags, not template_tags +1

Answer (score 2):

Follow Daniel and Ignacio's suggestions first. Also, its weird that you have `{% load produto_tags %}` in the top of the template but got an invalid block error: if `produto_tags` cannot be loaded, the error should be something like 'produto_tags is not a valid tag' blahblah. Could you please check the code and path structure you posted, again?

Comment: I just posted the answer. There was a conflict due another templatetag file with the same name from another app. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use `{{ produto | get_all_tags }}` instead.

The `{% ... %}` syntax is only valid for block tags such as `for`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Filters use `@register.filter`, not `@register.tag`.